# integral involving a bessel function

Tags: special-functions

Try to evaluate the integral:
$$
\int e^{-x^2}\dfrac{\Gamma(-1/2+ix)\Gamma(-1/2-ix)}{\Gamma(ix)\Gamma(-ix)}\Gamma(-1/4+ix)\Gamma(-1/4-ix)K_{2ix}(z)x,
$$
either over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{R}^+$ (there is some symmetry here).

Trying to use the fact that
$$
\dfrac{\Gamma(-1/2+ix)\Gamma(-1/2-ix)}{\Gamma(ix)\Gamma(-ix)}
=
\dfrac{x\tanh(\pi x)}{1+4x^2}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x\tanh(\pi x)}{\Gamma(3/4+ix/2)\Gamma(3/4-ix/2)}K_{ix}(a)K_{ix}(b)dx=
\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi ab}{a^2+b^2}}\exp\{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\}
$$
from Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. No luck so far. Would appreciate any help.